# Javascript API for Alfresco nodeRef

Tags: alfresco, nodereference

I have usecase to copy files from one contentstore to another contentstore in given frequency ( Eg once in month on a specific day)

I am using Alfresco crone job to invoke java script , which will copy(set new conentstore) files from one contentstore to another .  I have following question

- How do i get nodereference using javascript API ?
- Is there a way to get list of file in a specific folder and iterate through to set new conentstore ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using Enterprise or Community version?

Comment: Enterprese Edition  5.x version

Comment: When you say you are copying from one contentstore to another, can you be more specific? Have you configured multiple content stores within your Alfresco repository? Are you using the content store selector? Maybe share some code and put some psuedo code where you have the question.

Comment: Thanks for this respose , I have configured multiple contentStore .  I just resolved using javascript API.